# Book of the Month?

Tags: discussion

I just finished reading 'Kreativity For Kats' by Fritz Leiber.  It is a 1961 work now in the public domain and available for free in multiple formats at Project Gutenberg http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/51493

There is a very short intro, to make it fit into the science fiction magazine it was originally published in, but other then that this is a look inside the mind of a cat. A very appropriate book for our community.

```
They are the aliens among us—and
their ways and wonders are
stranger than extraterrestrials!
```

**So...** I read it and thought others might enjoy it, and "hey why don't we see about having a book of the month?"

If you like the idea of a book of the month feature in our Meta, take a look at this book and leave a response.

Answer (score 1):

This is apparently an antecedent to *Space-Time for Springers*, which is definitely SpecFic and considered one of the classics of the genre. I didn't know this earlier piece existed; thanks for the heads up.

But I think a book discussion would be more appropriate in the community wiki than here. It isn't metadiscussion.